# ¿Qué significa el error "Bad file descriptor" en python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket

Tengo este código en python3, el cual escucha por el puerto 80:

```
import socket  # The socket
serverd = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serverd.bind(("0.0.0.0", 80))
serverd.listen(10)
while True:
    serverc, addr = serverd.accept()
    recvmsg = serverc.recv(10240)
    objectstr = recvmsg.decode("utf-8")
    sendmsg = "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"
    objectbyte = sendmsg.encode()
    serverc.send(objectbyte)
serverd.close()
```

Al ejecutarlo, la consola retorna este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "core.py", line 6, in <module>
    serverc, addr = serverd.accept()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 187, in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Significa que estás intentando usar un *descriptor de archivo* no válido. Es decir, estas intentando usar un *archivo* (un socket en tu caso) que no ha sido abierto.

En tu código, el error está en la linea

```
serverd.bind(("0.0.0.0", 80))
```

¿ Cual es el error ? Que el puerto 80 está *reservado* y se necesitan permisos especiales para poder usarlo.

Todos los puertos `<= 1024` necesitan de permisos especiales para poder ser usados por los programas de usuario. Esto es herencia de los inicios de Internet, y fué un intento para ofrecer ciertas *garantias* de que, si te conectabas a uno de esos puertos, el programa que estaba escuchando era realmente lo que se esperaba.

Piensa por ejemplo en el protocolo *Telnet*, en el cual es necesario introducir el nombre de usuario y la contraseña. Si cualquiera pudiera hacer `bind( )` a ese puerto, sería *trivial* robar la identidad de cualquiera que se conectara.

En la actualidad, esas *garantias* carecen de sentido; pero en los inicios, cuando no había ordenadores personales, las máquinas eran *administradas* por un usuario especial, que era el único que podia utilizar esos puertos y decidir que programa responderia en dichos puertos.

Para solucionar tu problema, 2 soluciones:

1. Cambiar el puerto, de 80 a 8080 por ejemplo (cualquiera libre por
   encima del 1024).
2. Obtener los permisos necesarios para usar esos
   puertos. Si estas en Linux, haz

   sudo TUPROGRAMA